# List of column_names having dtypes as 'object'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Does anyone know how to make a list of column names which contain the names of columns which has dtypes as 'object'
Or in other words the columns containing strings

Please guys it ill be great help if u do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have following data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":["a","b","c"]})
df    
    a   b
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
```

Then the following line will do:

```
[nm for nm, dt in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes) if dt == "object"]
['b']
```

Comment: Man was reay helpfull..

Comment: Could you please explain to me what the zip() is doing here...